# Could not parse mapping document from resource Books.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

Why am i getting hibernate.invalidmappingexception when i try to save an object in database with hibernate..

*books.hbm.xml* (Inside the resource folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="Books" table="books">  
    <id name="id">  
     <generator class="increment"></generator>  
    </id>  
    <property name="name"></property>  
    <property name="author"></property>  
    <property name="count"></property>  
    <property name="description"></property>
  </class>  
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

*Hibernate.cfg.xml:*

```
    <hibernate-configuration> 
      <session-factory> 
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost/cybage </property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"> root </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"> yoga </property>   
        <mapping resource="Books.hbm.xml"/> 
   </session-factory> 
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

And *My project structure is*:

[image: the snapshot of folder structure and files stored...It seems there is something wrong with this]

I have placed the mapping files BOOKS.hbm.xml in resource folder and the Hibernate.cfg.xml in the META/classes folder

Comment: try to post your file hibernate configuration

Comment: post your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: <hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/cybage
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      yoga
   </property>

 
   <mapping resource="Books.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: Please, add full stack trace and will add it to the answer not to a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a full class name with a package in the `books.hbm.xml`

```
<class name="pack.Books" table="books">  

    .... 

</class>
```

You need to have the `resources` folder in the `main` folder to have all files in the `WEB-INF/classes`, after building a `war`. `WEB-INF/classes` will be in the class path by default.

You have `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `user.hbm.xml` in the `classes` folder — move all `xml` from the `classes` to the `resources`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
  <mapping resource="Books.hbm.xml"/>
```

With:

```
 <mapping resource="resources/Books.hbm.xml"/>
```

Adding the right path.

Comment: If he uses a valid maven build the `resources` will be in the `WEB-INF/classes` after build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide correct mapping path of hbm file in Hibernate.cfg.xml
so Just replace to

```
<mapping resource="resources/Books.hbm.xml"/>
```

Because your hbm file is located in resources folder so you need to provide same path.